# How to traverse/iterate a Dataframe with pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm a newbie for pyspark.
Here's my schema got from mongodb.
df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- machine_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- profiles: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- node_a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- log_content: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- log_content: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ...
 |    |-- node_b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- log_content: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- log_content: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- profile_4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ...
```

For each machine, I have 2 nodes, for each node, I have many profiles. I need to get duration distribution for each profile.
Such as for profile_1, count(1 <= duration < 2). What kinds of api of dataframe could I use?
All I thought of is to:
1. flatten node_a and node_b
new_df = df.selectExpr(flatten(df.schema, None, 2))
2. get new dataframes for node_a and node_b
df_a = new_df.selectExpr("machine_id", "node_a")
df_b = new_df.selectExpr("machine_id", "node_b")
3. Then flatten df_a and df_b, so that I could have 2 dataframes with below schema:

```
 |-- machine_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- profile_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- log_count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- log_att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_content: string (nullable = true)
 |-- profile_2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- log_count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- log_att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- log_content: string (nullable = true)
 |-- profile_3: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- profile_4: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- ...
```

I consider this as a very silly method. Is there any other "smarter" method?

Answer (score 0):

Ah... I finally find a new method to address it. Not sure if this is a good way, but it is surely better than the silly one

```
def flatten(schema, prefix=None):
    for field in schema.fields:
        dtype = field.dataType
        field_name = field.name
        name = prefix + '.' + field_name if prefix else field_name
        if field_name == "profiles" \
            or re.search(r'machine_[ab]', field_name \
            or re.match(r'profile_\d+', field_name)):
            flatten(dtype, prefix=name)
        elif re.search(r'profile_\d+', name):
            for sub_name in dtype.names:
                sub_names.append(name + '.' + sub_name)
            print(sub_names)
            create_new_table(sub_names)
    return
```